# Is my reasoning using limits correct for why =1+1/?

Tags: limits, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

let $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n} = \phi$$ by definition, where $$f_n$$ is the nth fibonacci number

then $$\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}1+\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}= \phi $$
$$\implies 1+\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}= \phi $$
$$\implies 1+\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f_{n}}{f_{n+1}}= \phi $$
$$\implies 1+(\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_{n}})^{-1}  = \phi $$
$$\implies 1+ \frac{1}{\phi}  = \phi $$

I am not sure if the reciprocal of a limit of ratios is the limit of the reciprocal of the ratios. Is my reasoning correct here?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be correct, referring to some additional, deserved information: $\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \right) \cdot \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 {x_n} \right) = 1$ for a continuous sequence $x_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f_n>0$, and $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is continuous in $(0, \infty) $, then is correct to say that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}}\right) ^{-1}.$$